# Store and access keyframes for animations

Tags: c++, animation, store, keyframe

I want to create an animation system in c++ in wich I store keyframes, that have a time and a value. Those values shall be interpolated during playback, so i need them sortet by their time variable. Because when interpolating, i allways want to interpolate only between last and next keyframe (how it's usually done).

How would I store the keyframes, so I can easily (and fast) access the keyframe before and after a specific time?

At first std::map came to my mind, but there I have problems with the correct order of the keyframes... Any ideas how to do this better?

Comment: you can have your own custom container if you don't want an STL one, by the way if you're proceeding sequentially vectors are probably a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::vector and keep the correct order of the keyframes. 
Assuming that the keyframes are sorted by time in the vector you can then extract the
relevant keyframe with `std::lower_bound` or `std::binary_search` in logarithmic time.

`std::map` internally keeps the elements sorted by the key
following a strict weak ordering criterion. So, if you use time as the key, you
will keep the correct order of the keyframes.

Personally, I would use std::vector.

Comment: So I can simply use a map? Didn't know they sort automatically.